# Use index.php for login and main content

Tags: php, session

Currently I have a very basic PHP login system. My index.php file simply checks if a session is set, if it isn't it redirects them to login.php. I see a lot of websites where the same effect is achieved but through the index of the site entirely.

For example, at http://twitter.com if I am not logged in I will land at simply twitter.com. If I am logged in I will also land at twitter.com just with different content. How can I achieve the same effect on my site?

I'm sure this is very basic but it's something I am yet to explore.

Thanks

Comment: Your index.php will hold most of your files/components, with the exception that if the user is logged in, you would do an `include` to a file if the condition is met/true.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Ahh I see, that makes perfect sense. So if the session is set, include bla.php (with all the main content), if it's not set include login.php etc.

Comment: Yes that's the basic concept and using an `else` condition.

Comment: if (user logged in) show this else show that. The `if` would usually be if a session is set

Comment: @JoelKidd Plus, all your included files must/will have `session_start();` or whatever other method you choose because someone may figure out the included file(s).

Comment: @JoelKidd MVC is a type of PHP Framework that uses routing logic and structural redundancy, and a very common structure that achieves the effect you speak of (index.php _is_ every page, just with different files included). Check out this [MVC Framework Tutorial](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Model-View-Controller-MVC.html) on a basic look at how this is achieved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple example how you can handle your welcome/user `index.php` site:

index.php

```
require_once('configFile.php'); // session_start();.. and other stuff

if ($logged) {

    require_once('userLogedIn/index.php'); 

} else {

    require_once('welcome/index.php');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lots of ways to do this but the below is a primitive example. Assuming your pseudo logic is something like...

```
if (!$logged_in) {
    redirect('login.php');
}
else {
    // show page content
}
```

You can do...

```
if (!$logged_in) {
    include('login.php');
}
else {
    include('page-content.php');
}
```

The includes aren't necessarily required but help to keep it tidy.

Answer (score 0):

First of all answer yourself the question if your index file can contain user supplied stuff. If so **DON'T DO IT!** The problem are possible attack vectors from that user supplied stuff against your login.

That said let me help you:

```
<?php

$session_id = session_id();

if (!empty($_COOKIE[$session_id]) && session_start() !== false && isset($_SESSION["user_id"])) {
  echo "index page";
}
elseif (isset($_POST["login"])) {
  // validate login ...
  if ($valid_login === true) {
    if (session_status() === PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {
      session_regenerate_id();
    }
    else {
      session_start();
    }
    $_SESSION["user_id"] = $user_id;
  }
}
else {
  echo "login page";
}

?>
```

I think you get the idea here. We now have a single file taking care of everything.

Comment: You're missing a very crucial component. Misplaced actually.

Comment: You have to be more specific than that.